# Converted c# proj(from vb) doesnt allow to add files

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have a c# project converted from VB.

When I say converted, I did not create a new project from scratch but I took the VB project changed all the file names, code and the proj file.

Project builds and works fine but when I try to add a new item it shows all the VB items in the list and not C#. Sorry I couldn't post the image (it requires at least 10 posts)

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you sure the new project is a C# project?

Comment: what do you mean by *shows all the VB items in the list and not C#*?

Comment: On the left there should also be categories for items to add. There should be a c# category. It probably had VB selected by default. Personally i would suggest making a new project and bring your files into that.

Comment: @PoweredByOrange: Yes it is. I am able to add the reference of this project and able to debug too.

Comment: @jbutler483: Right click on the project choose "Add - New Item" it shows me the vb items in the list.

Comment: @Jeffery Wieder- I looked for that too but couldnt find. All I can see if Visual Basic..and the Online menu.

Comment: what version of visual studio do you have currently?

Comment: @jbutler483 VS Pro 2012

Answer (score 0):

your 'Create new project should look something like (this is for 2012): [image]

```
      ^ ^ ^
      | | |
      | | |
       Here
```

Down the left hand side, you should see 'Visual C#'.

Selecting 'Visual Basic' will create a vb project, but you want to create a C# project.

**EDIT**

Following these steps would allow you to install further templates:

> To install project templates from the New Project dialog box
>
> On the File menu, click New, and then click Project. The New Project
>   dialog box opens.
>
> In the left pane, click Online Templates and expand the Templates
>   list.
>
> In the Templates list, select the category of templates to search for
>
> -- OR --
>
> Type one or more keywords in the Search box.
>
> A list of templates appears in the middle pane.

More information can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/ms185306(v=vs.100).aspx)

**EDIT 2**

To Help others coming across this question in the future;

The OP used [Sharp Develop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sd/) to convert from C# -> VB -> C#

The OP noted that the (main) difference in both the project files that they found was the initial C# project had below line immediately below the  tag:

```
Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props'
```

Comment: Thanks for the image. Yes, but surprisingly, I don't see the Visual C# or C++. All I can see is Templates (only Visual Bsic) and the next item is "Online"

Comment: Try installing "visual studio C# express".

Comment: I am able to see the Visual C# for all other projects except this converted project. Yeah, I know it's Weird.

Comment: in all honesty, for the work you'll do converting it, it'll be much easier creating a new C# project and just 'manually translating' it from VB to c#

Comment: I agree with you but I do not want to lose the change history of the files so I had no other option except converting the project itself.

Comment: As said in the comments, if they are 'converted' already, once you're in a new c# project it'll be a matter of 'Add->Existing item' and choosing the 'converted' classes

Comment: I should have done that. I went too ambitious to keep the project history as well. I like this approach. Thanks jbutler.

Comment: If this answered your question, the best way to say thanks would be to mark it as accepted (the tick to left of answer) :)

Comment: If this approach may help others: I converted my converted C# project to VB using SharpDevelop and then converted it back to C#.  The difference in both the project files that I found is the initial C# project had below line immediately below the <Project> tag:                    Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props'

Answer (score 0):

If this approach may help others: I converted my converted C# project to VB using SharpDevelop and then converted it back to C#. The difference in both the project files that I found is the initial C# project had below line immediately below the  tag: Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props'

Below is from jbutler

As said in the comments, if they are 'converted' already, once you're in a new c# project it'll be a matter of 'Add->Existing item' and choosing the 'converted' classes –